# How to only upload only the filename (not entire directly name+filename) to a google storage bucket

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage

I have found a way to upload multiple csv files at once into a google cloud storage bucket that satisfy certain criteria.  The problem I have is that when they all upload to the google storage bucket, the entire path name of the file is uploaded with it.  I am wanting to upload only the actual file name

I have tried using the os.path.basename but it doesn't work. Is there any other way to obtain just the basename before it gets uploaded OR is there a way simply to rename the file before it gets uploaded?

```
import glob 
import os 
from pathlib import Path
from os import listdir
from google.cloud import storage

GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = "O:\My Creds\creds.json"

for file in glob.glob("O:\Team Drives\AU_A\Raw_Dauts\Dynamets\**\*.csv", recursive = True):
   filename = os.path.basename(file)  # throught this would work but doesn't
   storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS)
   bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('bukcetang81')
   blob = bucket.blob("Dynamic_datasets/" +filename)
   blob.upload_from_filename(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you remove parameter "filename", instead hard code it with the name of the file itself:

```
for file in glob.glob("O:\Team Drives\AU_A\Raw_Dauts\Dynamets\**\*.csv", recursive = True):
       storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS)
       bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('bukcetang81')
       blob = bucket.blob(destination_filename)
       blob.upload_from_filename(source_filename)
```

Comment: but how would you do this for multiple files?  This is where I'm getting stuck at the moment

Comment: If the code block Ronnaver gives you the desired result, you can always change the logic of your uploading. For instance, You can scan the directory for the number value of the files needed for upload. You can then put this number into a int variable. Put the upload code block within a `for` loop and point `x` to the int variable you scanned. This is just a suggestion to a potential quick workaround to your issue.